# Pandas Dataframe: move multiple rows with the same column values into new specific rows

Tags: python, pandas

Ι get a large datasheet from SAP like the following one

| SKU | Warehouse Num | Available Stock | ..... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 001 | 1 | 45 |  |
| 001 | 2 | 0 |  |
| 001 | 3 | 6 |  |
| 002 | 1 | 9 |  |
| 002 | 2 | 32 |  |
| 002 | 3 | 7 |  |

And I want to create a new data frame using pandas that keeps unique SKU numbers and moves available stock from columns to specific rows. The data frame I want to create should look like the one below.

| SKU | Warehouse 001 | Warehouse 002 | Warehouse 003 | ..... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 001 | 45 | 0 | 6 |  |
| 002 | 9 | 32 | 7 |  |

I tried using `df.pivot_table` but couldn't get it working properly. Can anyone help me with that?

Comment: `df.pivot(index='SKU', columns='Warehouse Num', values='Available Stock')`? pivot_table also works?

Comment: Firstly `df['Warehouse Num']='00'+df['Warehouse Num'].astype(str)` then use the solution given by @HenryEcker and chain `.add_prefix('Warehouse ').rename_axis(index=None,columns=None)` to it

Comment: Or just `df.pivot("SKU", "Warehouse Num", "Available Stock").add_prefix("Warehouse 00")`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an application of `pivot` which is covered extensively in [How to pivot a dataframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47152691/15497888) so I offer this Community wiki as a place to outline a solution in a way that is easier to understand than the comments. But encourage reading of the linked duplicate to understand fully.

The following `pandas` functions are useful here:

1. [pivot](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html)
2. [astype](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.astype.html)
3. [str.zfill](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.zfill.html)
4. [add_prefix](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.add_prefix.html)
5. [reset_index](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html)

---

Complete Working Example:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'SKU': {0: 1, 1: 1, 2: 1, 3: 2, 4: 2, 5: 2},
                   'Warehouse Num': {0: 1, 1: 2, 2: 3, 3: 1, 4: 2, 5: 3},
                   'Available Stock': {0: 45, 1: 0, 2: 6, 3: 9, 4: 32, 5: 7}})

# long to wide
new_df = df.pivot(index='SKU', columns='Warehouse Num',
                  values='Available Stock')
# pad columns and index with zeros to 3 places
new_df.columns = new_df.columns.astype(str).str.zfill(3).rename(None)
new_df.index = new_df.index.astype(str).str.zfill(3)
# Add Prefix and return SKU to a column
new_df = new_df.add_prefix('Warehouse ').reset_index()
print(new_df)
```

`new_df`:

```
   SKU  Warehouse 001  Warehouse 002  Warehouse 003
0  001             45              0              6
1  002              9             32              7
```